I have created a custom function that finds the area of a triangle, but when I call it in the Shell it gives me an error
def area_of_triangle(base, height):

area = base * height /2

return area

thats my functions code, but when i go to call it in the shell like area_of_triangle(10,50) for example, it returns
Traceback (most recent call last): File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
area = area_of_triangle(10,15) NameError: name 'area_of_triangle' is not defined

I dont know if it means i have saved it in the wrong place, or am not calling it properly or need to import it or something but im lost

The body of a function has to be indented.

[ask] and [mre]

Move the function to the top

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Maybe focus on these two things in your code:

No proper indentation in your function.

Called the function before defining. I mean, you need to define the function first and then call it.
def area_of_triangle(base, height):
    area = base * height /2
    return area

area = area_of_triangle(10,15)



